# Javascript Function Not Defined contactAdvertiser

Tags: javascript

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.3.2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.3.2/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="contactAdvertiser()" href="#">Contact Advertiser</a>
<script>
function contactAdvertiser() {
swal({
  title: 'Contact Advertiser',
  type: 'info',
  html:
    'Interested in this product/service? Contact the advertiser!<br> ' +
    '<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel:'.$item->phonenumber.'"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br> ' +
    '<b><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #536DFE; href="sms:'.$item->phonenumber.'?body=Greetings%2C%20I%20am%20interested%20in%20your%20product%2Fservice%20posted%20on%20OfferMoon.%20$
  showCloseButton: true,
  confirmButtonText:
    'Done',
})
}
</script>
```

I do not know what is wrong with my code, I have tried many times to fix the "contactAdvertiser function not defined".

UPDATED CODE:

```js
'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel:'+ <?php $item->phonenumber ?>+'"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br>' +
    '<b><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #536DFE; href="sms:'+ <?php $item->phonenumber ?>+'?body=test"</a>' +
```

Comment: before you click, any other errors or warnings in the developer tools console? By the way, it's unusual to see a `<link` in the body of HTML

Comment: `'.$item->phonenumber.'` ... well, that's not kosher javascript - you MUST be getting an error in the console before you click about some sort of syntax error

Comment: @JaromandaX - nope, no errors at all.

Comment: No, no, this is in PHP, and that gets the user's phone number. @JaromandaX

Comment: Really - your function is invalid syntax - which browser are you using?

Comment: No no, this part of the code isn't PHP - it's javascript ... the total lack of `<?php ... ?>` tells me that - also the lack of [php] tag

Comment: I am using Chrome OS.

Comment: Chrome OS is off the list of browsers I'll ever use, if it doesn't see that as invalid javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX I intentionally removed the PHP markings because this is not related to PHP.

Comment: Oh and actually, I got a two syntax errors now: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
19-test-3:752 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: then why are you using PHP notation in javascript? javascript **does not understand** `$item->phonenumber` - it's meaningless

Comment: there you go, that's because you're using PHP in javascript ... the `>` in `->` is confusing javascript, because it isn't valid javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated code is almost there - the problem is you still don't understand how PHP works

try this

```
'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel:<?php $item->phonenumber ?>"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br>' +
'<b><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #536DFE; href="sms:<?php $item->phonenumber ?>?body=test"</a>' +
```

the phonenumber is "injected" by PHP within this string, "tel:phonenumber ?>">"

The problem with

```
'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel:'+ <?php $item->phonenumber ?>+'"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br>'
```

is that if the phonenumber is a string (contains spaces in the middle for example) your javascript will end up

```
'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel:'+ 02 1234 5678 +'"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br>'
```

and that's not valid javascript either

using

```
'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel:<?php $item->phonenumber ?>"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br>'
```

it becomes

```
'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFC107;" href="tel: 02 1234 5678"><b>Call Advertiser</b></a><br>'
```